# Analytic functions on smooth manifolds

Tags: analysis

If X is a smooth manifold why is the space of locally analytic functions on X does not make sense. Please Explain.
I mean can analytic functions be defined on smooth manifolds?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. What does not make sense?

Comment: Can locally analytic functions be defined on smooth manifolds?

Answer (score 1):

Remember what "analytic" (or locally analytic) would mean. A function $f:X\to \Bbb R$ would be analytic if for any chart $\phi:U\to X$ with $U\subseteq \Bbb R^n$ open, the function $f\circ \phi$ is analytic on $U$. The notion doesn't make sense on a smooth manifold because different charts may disagree on whether a given function is analytic.

For a specific example, take $X = \Bbb R$. Then there is one chart $\phi_1:\Bbb R\to X$ given by $\phi_1(x) = x$, and another chart $\phi_2:\Bbb R\to X$ given by
$$
\phi_2(x)= \cases{x + e^{-1/x^2} & if $x>0$\\x & if $x\leq 0$}
$$
These two charts are smoothly compatible, and thus they are both part of the standard maximal atlas on $X$, but they disagree on whether $f(x) = x$ is analytic. Specifically, $\phi_1$ thinks that $f$ is locally analytic at $0$, while $\phi_2$ doesn't.

Comment: In this case the transition maps $\phi_2\circ\phi^{-1}_1$  is not even smooth.

Comment: @Bull Why is it not smooth?

Comment: @Bull $\phi_1^{-1}(x)$ does _not_ mean $\frac{1}{\phi_1(x)}$. Rather, $\phi_1^{-1}$ is the _inverse function_ of $\phi_1$.

Comment: @Bull That's not what inverse function means. It does not mean that you multiply them to get $1$, it means that you compose them to get the identity function, $x\mapsto x$. So the inverse of $x$ is $x$.

Comment: didnt get what you are saying...

Comment: @Bull $^{-1}$, when applied to functions, can mean two different things. Either $f^{-1}$ means that $f(x)\cdot f^{-1}(x)=1$, or that $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$. You are thinking about the former, but we are actually using the latter with $\phi_1^{-1}(x)$.